# Submitting HTML text form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, submit

I have built a very simple website and paid for my .me domain. I have a simple text form for email addresses and a submit button. I would like to upload the email address to my server once the "submit" button is pressed.

I searched the internet but couldn't seem to find any help doing this. I would like the simplest solution possible. Could anyone direct me to the correct resources? Is this a relatively simple task that can be done with only HTML CSS and JS?

Comment: To receive data to your server you must use server side programming with languages such as PHP, ASP, NodeJS

Comment: Usually you would need to have some server side technology to achieve this.  With only client side technology (HTML, CSS and JS) this is not easily possible.

Comment: A half-solution would be to use a mailto: link, but that's not really uploading anything, just popping up the the user's email client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using HTML, CSS and JS wont do. You need a way of handling what the user is submitting to your server, some sort of a server side scripting language, PHP, Python, Perl, etc.

Here's a PHP sample

```
if(isset($_POST['email'] && !empty($_POST["email"])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    // save email address code here...
}
```

Comment: Ah. so there's nothing I can really copy and paste? I'm gonna need to learn some PHP or Python?

Comment: Yep. That would be the easiest solution. Choose PHP if your needs are that simple, I believe you'll have an easier time with it.

Comment: @user2391236 you should mark my answer as correct (assuming it answered your question)

Answer (score 2):

`I would like to upload the email address to my server once the "submit" button is pressed.`

For what purpose? To create a mailing list? The easiest way to do this is to sign up for an account at something like MailChimp or CampaignMonitor. They give you a simple form to place on your site that allows people to enter their email address and submit it to a database. Then, you log in to that third party service to manage the database, send out emails etc. Works very well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Windows Azure Mobile Services. Create a table to store the data and then you only need JavaScript, thus avoiding any Server Side tech. This is a paid for service of course but you can get a free trial. https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-how-to-use-client-library/#create-client

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is not save the information to a file, but save it to a Data Base.
You will need to learn PHP and MySQL (the easiest ones, and there is much tutorials about them)(and probably phpMyAdmin as well).
Look for tutorials, if you don'f find a good one, tell me.